# Solve the problem of executing code on OCHL

Tags: pine-script

As you know, during backtest, the code is only executed when the candle is closed, and this is not good at all for some backtests.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

I have an idea

For example, we want to test the strategy on a time frame for one minute
But we run the code on a time frame of one second and compare the time frame data of one minute with the time of one second and this way we get very close to that goal.

Something like the following code:

```
//@version=4
strategy("projheie hal moshkel bozorg", overlay=true)

function() =>
    rsiTfOt=rsi(close, 14)
    co = crossover(rsiTfOt, 30)
    cu = crossover(rsiTfOt, 70)
    [co, cu]
    
[co, cu] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", function())
    
if (co)
    strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
if (cu)
    strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
```

But this code has a logic error
Please guide me who has found a solution to this idea

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help:

```
//@version=4
strategy("projheie hal moshkel bozorg", overlay=true)

length = input( 14 )
overSold = input( 30 )
overBought = input( 70 )
price = close
vrsi = rsi(price, length)
co = crossover(vrsi, overSold)
cu = crossunder(vrsi, overBought)    
    
[buy, sell] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", [co, cu], lookahead = true)
    
if (buy)
    strategy.entry("RsiLE", strategy.long, comment="RsiLE")
if (sell)
    strategy.entry("RsiSE", strategy.short, comment="RsiSE")
```

Comment: I know this, I want to simulate the same parameter you mentioned for the backtest

Comment: Sorry, I've treated your original question wrong )

Comment: This unfortunately does not work,
Please look at the first photo :

https://ibb.co/hYN0bnq
Then look at the second photo :

https://ibb.co/hY6PNpt

Comment: got it. let's try `, lookahead = true`

Comment: Unfortunately the problem was not solved,
Please look at the photo below :
https://ibb.co/Hgb7Jv0